# Making sure all dependency versions are specified in dependencyManagement in maven

Tags: maven, build, versioning

I would like to make sure that a maven project does not have dependency versions specified in modules. Instead, I would like to enforce all dependency versions to be specified in the dependencyManagement section of the parent pom. That is, failing the build if a version is specified in the module instead of the parent pom. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Might be possible with this plugin configuration (taken from https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MENFORCER-19):

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
          <goals>
              <goal>analyze-dep-mgt</goal>
          </goals>
          <phase>verify</phase>
          <configuration>
              <failBuild>true</failBuild>
              <ignoreDirect>false</ignoreDirect>
          </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

`<ignoreDirect>false</ignoreDirect>` will look if there are direct overrides, and `<failBuild>true</failBuild>` will make the build fail.

Comment: I've seen this one, but it only works if you override versions in modules. I mean, I would want it to not only fail when things are actually really broken, but to enforce a good pattern of specifying versions in the parent pom. I.e. failing even if versions specified in the module do not override parent pom versions of the same package.

Comment: True, in the analyze-dep-mgt mojo code, nothing is raised if the dependency listed in a child module is not present in the depMgt section (see here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/plugins/tags/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/dependency/analyze/AnalyzeDepMgt.java in the getMismatch method). In fact, a probably easy patch can add the ability to also fail for dependencies used and not declared in the depMgt section.